# Java Web uploaded image can't display immediately

Tags: java, image, web, upload

I uploaded image to `apache-tomcat-8.0.22\webapp\MyProjectName\` that works fine. I want to display such image use `<img src='...' />`. It fails because of `404 error`, but I can very sure image is upload success in file system. What really made me crazy is after about 5 seconds fresh the page then the image can display success!

I want display image immediately after uploaded, how to do that? I use Spring MVC3.

code save upload file

```
public String save(MultipartFile mtFile) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "/" + mtFile.getOriginalFilename();
    String fileRealPath = servletContext.getRealPath(filePath);
    mtFile.transferTo(new File(fileRealPath));
    return filePath;
}
```

The `filePath` will be stored in database.

code display image

```
<image src=${rc.contextPath + filePath} />
```

The image can display but can't display immediately. Image type is jpg.
I start tomcat by eclipse.

Comment: plz provide more info..:D

Comment: Please provide code about you handle incoming data and how you write this data to disk.

Comment: provide the src which you used.

Comment: what is the image type?